# I'm getting multiple errors in Gamemaker in regards to moving the player in a room, and I'm not sure why it is happening

Tags: game-maker

Shouldn't this code move the player? It won't animate the player, but it should at least move it...
[image]

The top one is when I press Down, the next one is when I press Left, the second from the bottom shows when I press Up, and the last one is when I press Right.
[image]

All I want to do is move the player at this point, I'm not going to worry about adding the animations right now. If anyone knows how to help me, I would be extremely thankful!

Answer (score 0):

**Update: I just noticed your error codes from the second screenshot now. The issue is likely that you need to turn on physics for the room/object.**

Original reply:

What if instead of trying to set phy_position_x/y directly, which GM recommends against, you set the phy_speed_x/y? So for instance move right/left would look like this:

```
if moveRight
{
   phy_speed_x = spd;
}

if moveLeft
{
   phy_speed_x = -spd;
}
```

You may need to have "phy_speed_x = 0;" before the if statements to keep the object from moving when no button is pressed. I don't use the built-in physics system myself so I have not tested this.

Comment: Well if I just set phy_position_x/y to spd, then it would just teleport the player to the value of spd and -spd in the room, which is 6.5.